# unconventional foreign key fields maps to NULL in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6. I have two models PowerLine and PowerSource. PowerSource has a foreign key column that points to PowerLine. The problem is that the PowerLine object is populating with List of PowerSource but the SourcePowerLine navigation property of PowerSource is always NULL. My models are as follows :

```
public class PowerLine
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }                                    
    public virtual ICollection<PowerSource> PowerSources { get; set; }    
}

public class PowerSource
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public int SourcePowerLineID {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("SourcePowerLineID")]        
    public virtual PowerLine SourcePowerLine { get; set; }                                                         
 }
```

I tried Column(Order) attribute as well to set the correct order also I tried to use Fluent API like as follows :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PowerSource>()
                    .HasRequired(c => c.SourcePowerLine )
                    .WithMany(b => b.PowerSources)
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.SourcePowerLineID);
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly but did you try: context.PowerSources.Include("SourcePowerLine")

Answer (score 0):

Your `[ForeingKey()]` attribute is not really pointing to anywhere, try:

```
[ForeignKey("PowerLine")]
public int SourcePowerLineID { get; set; }
```

Comment: your solution gives me the following error : 



`Additional information: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'SourcePowerLineID' on type 'power.Model.PowerSource' is not valid. The navigation property 'PowerLine' was not found on the dependent type 'power.Model.PowerSource'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.`